# Dynamic Array: Separating Numbers into Even and Odd Using C

Tags: c, dynamic-arrays

My program should first ask for the number of integers to read and dynamically allocate an array just big enough to hold the number of values I read. Then, I need to categorize these values into odd and even.

This is the code I've tried

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void){

//declare variables
int i; //loop counter
int count; //integer amount from user
int j = 0; int k = 0;

// read in integer count from user
printf("enter the amount of numbers: ");
scanf("%d", &count);

// declare pointer 
int *number = malloc(sizeof(int)*count);
int *evens = malloc(sizeof(int)*count);
int *odds = malloc(sizeof(int)*count);

// declare variable
//int odds_count = 0;
//int evens_count = 0;

//loop to read in numbers from user
for (i=0; i<count; i++){
    printf("enter number %02d: ",i+1);
    scanf("%d",(number+i));
    printf("you entered %d\n", *(number+i)); //--- entered values are correct here
    if (*(number+i)% 2 ==0){
        *(number+i) = *(evens+j);
        j++;
        //evens_count++;
    } else {
        *(number+i) = *(odds+k);
        k++;
    }
    printf("you entered %d\n", *(number+i));  //---entered values become 0
}
//print array elements
printf("\nEntered array elements are:\n");
for(i=count;i>0;i--)
{
    printf("%d ",*(number+i));
}
printf("\n");

// print out even numbers
printf("even numbers: ");
for (i=0;i<j;i++){
    printf("%5d",*(evens+i));
}
printf("\n");

// print out odd numbers
printf("odd numbers: ");
for (i=0;i<k;i++){
    printf("%5d",*(odds+i));
}
printf("\n");

return 0;
}
```

No matter what input I enter, the output only displays 0.
E.g:

```
Input- 1, 2, 3
Output-
Evens: 0
Odds: 0 0
```

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it C#? It does not look.

Comment: `*(number+i) = *(evens+j)` is exactly equivalent to `number[i] = evens[j]`, and probably was intended to be `evens[j] = number[i]`

Comment: When you do `*(number+i) = *(evens+j);` -- what is the value at `evens[j]`? Look above the assignment in your code and point out where the `evens` array values are initialized?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Got it. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

While getting the input from user, try putting an '&' symbol before your variable name. I think that should work.

```
scanf("%d",&(number+i));
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: Sad coding, `(numbers+1)` is equivalent to `&numbers[i]`. What you have is a *pointer-to-pointer-to-int* (and likely a SegFault)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Answer] pages soon.  This advice is often correct, but it is not in this case, because `number` is already a pointer to an integer so `(number + i)` is also a pointer to an integer — so your advice is formally wrong.  Please remove this answer (before it gets down-voted and deleted anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Your biggest issues regarding assigning values occurs when you attempt to assign `evens[j]` and `odds[j]` to `numbers[i]` before the elements of either `evens` or `odds` have been initialized. Following your call to `malloc` for each `evens` and `odds` the block of memory allocated contains whatever garbage values happen to be in that memory region at the time of allocation. `malloc` does not initialize the content of the memory in any way and leave the values indeterminate. If you want to both allocate and zero all bytes, you can use `calloc` instead of `malloc`.

This problem occurs here:

```
    if (*(number+i)% 2 ==0){
        *(number+i) = *(evens+j);
        j++;
        //evens_count++;
    } else {
        *(number+i) = *(odds+k);
        k++;
    }
```

Look carefully, you check whether `numbers[i]` is even/odd with `% 2 == 0`, but then attempt to overwrite the value at `numbers[i]` with either `evens[j]` or `odds[k]` -- **this is backwards**. The intent would be to assign the value in `numbers[i]` to either `evens[j]` or `odds[k]`, e.g.

```
    if (number[i] % 2 ==0){
        evens[j] = number[i];
        j++;
        //evens_count++;
    } else {
        odds[k] = number[i];
        k++;
    }
```

Next, your use of variables is jumbled. You don't need all the different `i, j, k` counters declared at the beginning of `main()`. For the past 20 years, since C99, you can declare the loop variable within the `for` loop declaration itself. This eliminates the chance that your use of your loop variable will conflict with another use of `i, j, k` somewhere else in the program.

You have `count, odd_count & even_count`, those are the only counters you need.

Further, you need to VALIDATE *every* User Input and *every* Allocation. Otherwise, you risk invoking *Undefined Behavior* with the slip of a keystroke or when (not "if") an allocation returns `NULL`. Validate every critical step.

Putting those measures to use, you can simplify your declaration to:

```
    int count,          /* integer amount from user     */
        odd_count = 0,  /* odd count (initialized zero) */
        even_count = 0, /* even count (initialized zero)*/
        *number,        /* declare pointers             */
        *evens,
        *odds;
```

You can validate your input with:

```
    /* read in integer count from user (VALIDATE every input) */
    printf("enter the amount of numbers: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &count) != 1) {
        fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {   /* loop count times for input */
        printf ("enter number %2d: ", i + 1);
        if (scanf ("%d", &number[i]) != 1) {    /* validate EVERY input */
            fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }
        if (number[i] % 2 == 0)     /* assign, increment evens count */
            evens[even_count++] = number[i];
        else                        /* same for odds */
            odds[odd_count++] = number[i];
    }
```

And you can validate your allocations:

```
    /* allocate count integers each pointer (VALIDATE every allocation) */
    if ((number = malloc (count * sizeof *number)) == NULL) {
        perror ("malloc-number");
        return 1;
    }
    if ((evens = malloc (count * sizeof *evens)) == NULL) {
        perror ("malloc-evens");
        return 1;
    }
    if ((odds = malloc (count * sizeof *odds)) == NULL) {
        perror ("malloc-odds");
        return 1;
    }
```

Then it is simply a matter of looping `i = 0; i < count` to output the `number`, `i = 0; i < even_count` to output `evens` and finally `i = 0; i < odd_count` to output `odds`, e.g.

```
    puts ("\n numbers\n--------");      /* output each array on its own */
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        printf ("%8d\n", number[i]);

    puts ("\n   evens\n--------");
    for (int i = 0; i < even_count; i++)
        printf ("%8d\n", evens[i]);

    puts ("\n    odds\n--------");
    for (int i = 0; i < odd_count; i++)
        printf ("%8d\n", odds[i]);
```

And Finally, you can output all 3 arrays at once with:

```
    /* output all arrays together */
    puts ("\nnumbers      even      odd\n-------- -------- --------");
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {       /* loop printing number */
        printf ("%8d", number[i]);
        if (i < even_count) {               /* if i < even_count */
            printf (" %8d", evens[i]);      /* output evens */
            if (i < odd_count)              /* if odds too, output them */
                printf (" %8d\n", odds[i]);
            else
                putchar ('\n');             /* no more odds output '\n' */
        }
        else if (i < odd_count)             /* if only odds left, output */
            printf ("%18d\n", odds[i]);
        else
            putchar ('\n');
    }
```

At the end, don't forget to free the memory you allocate, e.g.

```
    free (number);  /* don't forget to free what you allocated */
    free (evens);
    free (odds);
```

Putting it altogether, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    int count,          /* integer amount from user     */
        odd_count = 0,  /* odd count (initialized zero) */
        even_count = 0, /* even count (initialized zero)*/
        *number,        /* declare pointers             */
        *evens,
        *odds; 

    /* read in integer count from user (VALIDATE every input) */
    printf("enter the amount of numbers: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &count) != 1) {
        fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    /* allocate count integers each pointer (VALIDATE every allocation) */
    if ((number = malloc (count * sizeof *number)) == NULL) {
        perror ("malloc-number");
        return 1;
    }
    if ((evens = malloc (count * sizeof *evens)) == NULL) {
        perror ("malloc-evens");
        return 1;
    }
    if ((odds = malloc (count * sizeof *odds)) == NULL) {
        perror ("malloc-odds");
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {   /* loop count times for input */
        printf ("enter number %2d: ", i + 1);
        if (scanf ("%d", &number[i]) != 1) {    /* validate EVERY input */
            fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }
        if (number[i] % 2 == 0)     /* assign, increment evens count */
            evens[even_count++] = number[i];
        else                        /* same for odds */
            odds[odd_count++] = number[i];
    }

    puts ("\n numbers\n--------");      /* output each array on its own */
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        printf ("%8d\n", number[i]);

    puts ("\n   evens\n--------");
    for (int i = 0; i < even_count; i++)
        printf ("%8d\n", evens[i]);

    puts ("\n    odds\n--------");
    for (int i = 0; i < odd_count; i++)
        printf ("%8d\n", odds[i]);

    /* output all arrays together */
    puts ("\nnumbers      even      odd\n-------- -------- --------");
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {       /* loop printing number */
        printf ("%8d", number[i]);
        if (i < even_count) {               /* if i < even_count */
            printf (" %8d", evens[i]);      /* output evens */
            if (i < odd_count)              /* if odds too, output them */
                printf (" %8d\n", odds[i]);
            else
                putchar ('\n');             /* no more odds output '\n' */
        }
        else if (i < odd_count)             /* if only odds left, output */
            printf ("%18d\n", odds[i]);
        else
            putchar ('\n');
    }

    free (number);  /* don't forget to free what you allocated */
    free (evens);
    free (odds);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/number_evens_odds
enter the amount of numbers: 10
enter number  1: 21
enter number  2: 22
enter number  3: 23
enter number  4: 24
enter number  5: 119
enter number  6: 121
enter number  7: 131
enter number  8: 140
enter number  9: 141
enter number 10: 143

 numbers
--------
      21
      22
      23
      24
     119
     121
     131
     140
     141
     143

   evens
--------
      22
      24
     140

    odds
--------
      21
      23
     119
     121
     131
     141
     143

numbers      even      odd
-------- -------- --------
      21       22       21
      22       24       23
      23      140      119
      24               121
     119               131
     121               141
     131               143
     140
     141
     143
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.